# Отправить динамически cookie jquery

Tags: jquery, сортировка, cookie

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="" data-sort="id">ID</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-sort="title">Заголовку</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-sort="time">Дате</a></li>
</ul>
```

Задача:

Отправить cookie по клику по ссылке и передать в cookie значение которое находится в атрибуте `data-sort`

Прошу помощи в написании функции jquery!

Comment: Куда отправить? С каким именем?

Comment: 1. setcookie 2. sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за настроек безопасности JS, запись в cookie здесь невозможна, но у Вас должно работать:

```js
$("ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var sort = e.target.dataset.sort;
  // Cookies.set('sort', sort, {
  //     domain: 'my.site.com',
  //     path: '',
  //     expires: 365 
  // });
  // Cookies.get('sort');
  console.log("sort is: %o", sort);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2.2.0/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="" data-sort="id">ID</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-sort="title">Заголовку</a></li>
    <li><a href="" data-sort="time">Дате</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [JavaScript Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

  - атрибут [path](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#path)
  - атрибут [domain](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#domain)
  - атрибут [expires](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#expires)
- [Использование data-* атрибутов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: мне нужно чтоб данные cookie работали только на определенной странице. например: website.com/new Подскажите реализацию.

Comment: @verstala https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#path и https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#domain

Comment: Благодарю! все работает.